# Definite integral involving arctan and tan

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I was solving a problem posed on Moldavian National Mathematical Olympiad for 12th grade in 2012. The question was the following:

**Problem.** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)=\frac{\arctan x^2}{x^2+1}$. Consider the primitive of it to be $F(x)$, such that $F(0)=0$. Find the follwoing limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}F(x)$$

By using substitution $x=\tan u$ I reduced problem to the calculation of the folloing definte integral.

$$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \arctan(\tan^2 x)\, dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

However my attempts to calculate it failed. I tried changing $x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-x$, but it didn't help much. I used WolfamAlpha to find the answer, but I can't prove it.

Comment: What are your thoughts ? WHat have you done ?

Comment: I tried substiuing $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ instead of $x$, and then add those two integrals up, but it didn't help much.

Comment: Is it not true that there are many questions of the same structure that are awarded up votes? So why not this one?

Answer (score 2):

Translate the function $x \to \arctan \tan^2 x$ by vector $(-\pi/4, -\pi/4)$ and you'll see that such obtained function is odd. Hence it's straightforward to show that the integral is equal to:
$$\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4}$$